# UIImagePicker to new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an app that is is suppose to take an image from library or camera and do some stuff with it. I have managed to load the picture with :

```
UIImagePickerController *picker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
if ([@"cam" isEqual:[[sender titleLabel] text]]) { 
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
} else if ([@"album" isEqual:[[sender titleLabel] text]]) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

works fine. but what i am trying to do is when a picture is chosen, i want to go to a new view.
i have the method `changeView` that goes to a specified view but when i call it from the 
`-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`
it doesn't work for some reason.

The program goes into the `segue` class but nothing happens.

Comment: Add NSLog(@"Image picker was dismissed!"); to the (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info method to see if it is being called. If it is, it's a problem with the way you're changing your view. If it's not being called, it's something else (probably a problem with your image picker).

Comment: Sorry about the code being formatted as plaintext - it's not letting me format the code for some reason...

Comment: can I see your imagePickerController method?

Comment: Seems that you are presenting the imagepicker controller from another view controller.  Perhaps the simplest approach is not to try and present another view, but rather to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Comment: thenk you for the advice but i want the picker to stay open so that when i finish in the second view and go back it will be open and redy for another image pick (and even when i dismiss it, it still doesn't work)

picker controller is : 
self.appDelegate.theImg = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self goToNextView:@"toImgViewer" from:@"SecondViewController"];

goToNextView :

-(void)goToNextView:(NSString *) segueIdentifier from:(NSString *)viewSender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:viewSender];
}

Comment: oh man sorry its so mushed dont know how to fix it =\

Comment: I think I would architect it differently, as I dont think (not completely sure) that an ImagePicker can be used the way you are describing.  How I would do it is to have your view controller be the main view, and in your viewDidLoad, call to bring up you UIImagePickerController.  when the user selects the image, bring it back into your main view controller for working on.  When the back button is pressed, use that action to re-bringup your UIImagePickerController.

Comment: By the way, I have developed an app that does exactly what Im explaining (with the exception of bringing the UIImagePickerController up at startup), and to the user, it does the same exact thing you are asking, it is simply how you are trying to architect it in the backend.

Comment: thank you i did that and the view is passing to the new on but when i go back to the first view it doesn't go into the `viewdidload` because it isnt loaded, i never closed it... is ther something like `viewreopened` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the "finishpicking" method for the imagepicker, I would call:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then, in your "presenting" view controller instantly perform your segue to the second view without animation.  This will make it seem like the imagepicker view and the second view your present are part of the same view controller.  This way, you also only present a single modal view controller at any given point.  If you'd like to pass data between the modal view controllers, set up a delegate protocol of the imagepicker, pass the image data to the presenting view controller, and then push it to the second modal view controller in the

```
prepareForSegue
```

method by setting the properties of the

```
segue.destinationViewController
```